# Hiding fields in Quick View form with JS not working

Tags: crm, powerapps, dynamics-crm-365, powerapps-modeldriven

I need to hide few fields in a Quick View Form based on an Option Set (Choice) selection in that Quick View form. However it is not working, so am sharing the code I used for the same here. In my code, I am trying to hide certain fields if the option selected is not equal to a particular value...

function hideFields(executionContext) {

```
var formContext = executionContext.getFormContext();

var quickViewControl = formContext.ui.quickForms.get("General");

if (quickViewControl != undefined) {

    if (quickViewControl.isLoaded()) {

           var orgtypevalue = quickViewControl.getControl("new_organizationtype").getValue();

           if (orgtypevalue != 248870006) {

           quickViewControl.getControl("new_recipienttype").setVisible(false);

           quickViewControl.getControl("new_businesstype").setVisible(false);

           quickViewControl.getControl("new_businesstypecode").setVisible(false);

           quickViewControl.getControl("new_businesstypecharacteristicstypecode").setVisible(false);             

           return;

           }

           else {

           // Wait for some time and check again

           setTimeout(getAttributeValue, 10, executionContext);

           }

}

else {

    console.log("No data to display in the quick view control.");

    return;

}

else {

        quickViewControl.getControl("new_recipienttype").setVisible(true);

        quickViewControl.getControl("new_businesstype").setVisible(true);

        quickViewControl.getControl("new_businesstypecode").setVisible(true);

        quickViewControl.getControl("new_businesstypecharacteristicstypecode").setVisible(true);            

        return;
```

}

}

}

I need to know where am I wrong. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to debug, seen any errors in browser developer toolbar console?

Answer (score 1):

you need to update the following
first if version 9 I am updating this
"var quickViewControl = formContext.ui.quickForms.get("General");"
to "var quickViewControl = formContext._ui._quickForms.get("General");"
&
"var orgtypevalue = quickViewControl.getControl("new_organizationtype").getValue();"
to
"var orgtypevalue = quickViewControl.getAttribute("new_organizationtype").getValue();"
& update else with message to wait and call the function again like this
"setTimeout(hideFields, 10, executionContext);"
and add else for the If of "quickViewControl != undefined"

Kindly find the updated code:
function hideFields(executionContext) {

```
var formContext = executionContext.getFormContext();

var quickViewControl = formContext._ui._quickForms.get("General");

if (quickViewControl != undefined) {

    if (quickViewControl.isLoaded()) {

           var orgtypevalue = quickViewControl.getAttribute("new_organizationtype").getValue();

           if (orgtypevalue != 248870006) {

           quickViewControl.getControl("new_recipienttype").setVisible(false);

           quickViewControl.getControl("new_businesstype").setVisible(false);

           quickViewControl.getControl("new_businesstypecode").setVisible(false);

           quickViewControl.getControl("new_businesstypecharacteristicstypecode").setVisible(false);             

           return;

           }

           else {

           // Wait for some time and check again

           setTimeout(hideFields, 10, executionContext);

           }

}

else {

    //console.log("No data to display in the quick view control.");

    //return;
    setTimeout(hideFields, 10, executionContext);

}
}
```

}